# How to convert a json array into a flex 4 array (as3)?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, json, flex4

friends... my json array is

```
{"result":[{"status":0,"statusmsg":"Sorry, that's an invalid domain\n","rawout":null,"options":null}]}
```

how to convert this a json array into a flex 4 array (as3)?

Thanks for all help's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to download the as3corelib library and add it to your Library path
https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

You can then use the JSON decode method which will return an Object.

```
    var object:Object = JSON.decode( jsonString );
```

but you should be able to coerce your Object into an Array

```
    var array:Array = object as Array;
```

if for some reason, this doesn't work, you could try

```
    var array:Array = [];
    for( var prop:String in obj )
        array.push( obj[prop] );
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to send json through javascript, el, in a jsf page,
first i enconde the the arraylist of objects with the flexjson library in java.

2) the this object i put it in a java bean
3) the i call the javascript with the oncomplete event
4) like this callapp(#{bean.jsonString})
5) this is received in flex with the external interface
ExternalInterface.addCallback

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e92.html

6) then something weird occurs, the json string is converted in a array of objects of ACTIONSCRIPT
so i just have to loop through the array, and obtain the objects properties and buala …

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler way using flex 4.5 internal library (haven't test with flex 4)

```
import com.adobe.serializers.json.JSONDecoder;
var j:JSONDecoder= new JSONDecoder();   
var obj:Object= j.decode(json string);
myarray= obj as ArrayCollection;
```